# Specify pull reconciliation differently per branch on gitconfig

Tags: git, git-config

After updating to Git 2.28 I realized the [conditional includes](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes). However I was unable to find a way to set a different pull reconciliation option for `master(main)` other than the rest.

So for the `master(main)` branch I want to have `--ff-only` while for other branches I'd go with   `--rebase`

Is there a way to do it inside the main `.gitconfig` file, just using [`onbranch`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codeonbranchcode)?

The only solution I was able to come up with was:

**.gitconfig**

```
[includeIf "onbranch:master"]
   path = ~/.gitconfigmaster
```

and then create a `.gitconfigmaster` having:

```
[pull]
   ff = only
```

Answer (score 0):

A better fit would probably be to use the [`branch.*`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtmergeOptions) options :

```
# default '--rebase' for everyone :
git config pull.rebase true

# for the 'master' branch: override the global 'pull.rebase' option
git config branch.master.rebase false
git config branch.master.mergeOptions --ff-only
```